# Is it ok to pass the amount through URL in stripe payment

Tags: python, flutter, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I have a flutter application that uses Futter stripe package to integrate the stripe payment gateway. According to the app when user tapped on Pay now button it calls to a python backend and then I am expecting to create a stripe **paymentIntent** and return it back to the app. But the problem is is it safe to pass the **amount** that needs to charge directly from the URL like `http://localhost:4242/payment?amount=2000`.

If not how I can calculate the amount on the server-side?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you explain this a bit? I can't understand

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with the Flutter framework, but if there is any way that your customer would be able to intercept this request and change the query param then savvy users could do so to underpay you.

If the Flutter package lets you leverage Product and Price objects, then these could be used to lock down the amounts associated with them.  Alternatively, you could pass parameters from your frontend that map to amounts controlled in your backed.